# How to rename a file after upload with Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

Is there a way to rename files after upload? I want files to match model id after it is saved:

```
# image.rb

after_create :rename_file

def rename_file
  file.rename!(id)
end
```

But I can't find a simple way to do this.

**Update** The method `file.move_to` was in Carrierwave 0.9.0 but was removed since.

Comment: have you read this wiki [How to: Create random and unique filenames for all versioned files](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files) ?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964255/how-to-update-rename-a-carrierwave-uploaded-file

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work, I guess Carrierwave has change since. And I don't want random and unique filenames. After the image is saved I do know it's ID. All I need is to rename generated files and update the filename in the model.

Comment: @firedev you find any solution